# Arrow key bindings not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to get the four arrow keys to be bound to a command in my `ViewModel`, but they are not working. I have a `ContentControl` in a `Window` with `InputBindings` like so:

```
<ContentControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding EndCmd}" Key="Esc" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding PanUpCmd}" Key="Up" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding PanDownCmd}" Key="Down" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding PanLeftCmd}" Key="Left" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding PanRightCmd}" Key="Right" />
</ContentControl.InputBindings>
```

In my `ViewModel`:

```
public RelayCommand EndCmd { get; set; }
public RelayCommand PanUpCmd { get; set; }
public RelayCommand PanDownCmd { get; set; }
public RelayCommand PanLeftCmd { get; set; }
public RelayCommand PanRightCmd { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    EndCmd = new RelayCommand(End);
    PanUpCmd = new RelayCommand(PanUp);
    PanDownCmd = new RelayCommand(PanDown);
    PanLeftCmd = new RelayCommand(PanLeft);
    PanRightCmd = new RelayCommand(PanRight);
}

//functions that the commands call here
```

Now, the Escape key works fine, but the four arrow keys do not. Why is this? They are set up exactly the same. I thought maybe it was something to do with the `DataContext` so I put the `KeyBinding`s in the Window`s`InputBindings` but it was the same issue.

Edit: I've tested every key on my keyboard. Every key fires properly except the four arrow keys. I checked if the `Content` of the `ContentControl` was swallowing the events, and it was not. In fact, the `Control` that is the `Content` has it's own keydown event, which is also never called, nor is the previewkeydown, with the arrow keys.

Comment: That `Viewmodel` class will not compile... Also usually a `VM` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, is this a work in progress? Can you show the whole xaml code?

Comment: What's the `Content` of the `ControlControl`? Maybe it handles and "swallows" the key events? It's not a binding since the `EndCmd` works just fine.

Comment: If the content control doesn't have any UI elements, these commands wont fire, I was able to replicate the issue on my end. One trick I did was set the `Focusable = True` and when the UI element had focus it works just fine.

Comment: Was missing a bracket, but yes the ViewModel compiles and it does implement propertychanged. I only showed (what I thought) were the relevant parts. The content is a third party map control. I'll test if it's swallowing the key events, but it's strange that the escape key works fine.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you were right. I had a textbox in the window which was always the focus. Once tabbed to the contentcontrol, the events started working.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code and it seems to work fine.

The only reason I can think for this not to work in your case (especially if `Esc` works, but not the other keys) is that whatever content you're using inside of the `ContentControl` also contains input bindings for the direction keys.

In this case, the bindings in the content would override the bindings you've set for the `ContentControl` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow keys are handled by **KeyboardNavigation** default.
You should disable **KeyboardNavigation** and make sure control focusable.

```
  <Grid Background="{Binding Background}" KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="None" Focusable="True">
                <Grid.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="local:OpsCommands.MoveLeft" />
                    <KeyBinding Key="Up" Command="local:OpsCommands.MoveUp" />
                    <KeyBinding Key="Right" Command="local:OpsCommands.MoveRight" />
                    <KeyBinding Key="Down" Command="local:OpsCommands.MoveDown" />
                </Grid.InputBindings>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public ICommand PanRightCmd 
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SearchBarEnterCmdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SearchBarEnterCmdProperty, value); }
    }
```

...

```
            PanRightCmd= new RelayCommand(o => PanRightCmdExecute());
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/

Comment: Consider adding some explanation of your code, that would help a lot if the c-sharpcorner post goes dead.