# WPF arrow page navigation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to navigate between pages in WPF using arrow keys. I can not use the default frame navigation as it does not switch my View Models along with the pages. I've created a custom navigation which works when using a mouse to click the navigation buttons, but I would like to enable users to navigate with arrow keys as well.

Guess I could create an attached property which would listen for arrow key presses, but I feel that there should be an easier, pure WPF way how to achieve this. So far I have:

```
<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="R" Command="{Binding Application.GoBack, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.Instance}}"/>
</Page.InputBindings>
```

This code does exactly what I need. Basically all I want to do is to replace the "R" with something like "LeftArrow", but I just can't figure out the correct key name. I've tried "Left" but it does not work.

Could anybody please point out what I'm missing? Thank you.

Comment: You can refer to [msdn specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.key?view=netframework-4.8), _Left 23 The Left Arrow key_

Comment: It's easy ("Left" is for left arrow), but you will immediately run into [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55710443/1997232) issue if focus is set somewhere inside the control which also wants to use arrow keys.